Terraform Provider Plugin Crashed
My Terraform code has been working fine up until this afternoon.  I have not knowingly made any changes when when I did a plan / apply / destroy I have started getting this error.
Any suggestions on how to resolve this?
Plan: 21 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
╷
│ Error: Plugin did not respond
│
│   with data.aws_subnets.subnets,
│   on data.tf line 18, in data "aws_subnets" "subnets":
│   18: data "aws_subnets" "subnets" {
│
│ The plugin encountered an error, and failed to respond to the plugin.(*GRPCProvider).ReadDataSource call. The plugin logs may contain more details.
╵
╷
│ Error: Plugin did not respond
│
│   with data.aws_subnets.batch_subnets,
│   on data.tf line 30, in data "aws_subnets" "batch_subnets":
│   30: data "aws_subnets" "batch_subnets" {
│
│ The plugin encountered an error, and failed to respond to the plugin.(*GRPCProvider).ReadDataSource call. The plugin logs may contain more details.
╵
╷
│ Error: Plugin did not respond
│
│   with module.batch_security_group.aws_security_group.this_name_prefix[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/batch_security_group/main.tf line 37, in resource "aws_security_group" "this_name_prefix":
│   37: resource "aws_security_group" "this_name_prefix" {
│
│ The plugin encountered an error, and failed to respond to the plugin.(*GRPCProvider).ReadResource call. The plugin logs may contain more details.
╵
╷
│ Error: Plugin did not respond
│
│   with module.rsdl_batch.aws_batch_job_definition.this["rsdl-core"],
│   on .terraform/modules/rsdl_batch/main.tf line 265, in resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "this":
│  265: resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "this" {
│
│ The plugin encountered an error, and failed to respond to the plugin.(*GRPCProvider).PlanResourceChange call. The plugin logs may contain more details.
╵



Stack trace from the terraform-provider-aws_v5.49.0_x5 plugin:

panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not map[string]interface {}

Error: The terraform-provider-aws_v5.49.0_x5 plugin crashed!

This is always indicative of a bug within the plugin. It would be immensely
helpful if you could report the crash with the plugin's maintainers so that it
can be fixed. The output above should help diagnose the issue.


What did not work
Adding some of my troubleshooting steps:

removed the .terraform dir, terraform lock file and reran a terraform init --upgrade
This did not work.


What worked
I removed all of my dependencies in the code to my data resources, specifically the one that was looking up the subnets and the vpc info.
I replaced the references to these in my code with exact values and then ran a terraform destroy.
After the destroy I readded the data resources and readded their usage in my code and then a terraform apply ...this time it worked.  I have no idea why.

Since this is caused by a bug in the hashicorp/aws provider, I think your best path would be to report the bug in the AWS provider repository. It's impossible to suggest a workaround without knowing what caused the bug, and the maintainers of the provider are best equipped to diagnose that.

These issues seem similar to what you encountered; if you think it's the same, you could instead just provide more information in one of the existing issues: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/37422 https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/37349
